# Publishing is failing for Publish Settings Page from all the DXA Publications

Tags: publishing, dxa, content-manager, publishingfailed

We are trying to Publish the Publish Settings Page, but its getting failed showing below error:  **(80040356) 
Invalid parameter: variantId (schemasform%20core.schemas)**. 

StackTrace :

> > Invalid parameter: variantId (schemasform%20core.schemas).   Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService Errorcode: 854 User: NT
> >     AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE  StackTrace Information Details:    at
> >     Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.Binary.AssertValidVariantId(String
> >     variantId)    at
> >     Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.Binary..ctor(Stream
> >     content, String filename, IdentifiableObject location, String
> >     variantId, Component relatedComponent, String mimeType,
> >     RenderInstruction renderInstruction)    at
> >     Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderedItem.AddBinary(Stream
> >     content, String filename, StructureGroup location, String variantId,
> >     Component relatedComponent, String mimeType)    at
> >     Sdl.Web.Tridion.Common.TemplateBase.PublishJson(String json, Component
> >     relatedComponent, StructureGroup sg, String filename, String
> >     variantName)    at
> >     Sdl.Web.Tridion.Common.TemplateBase.PublishJsonData(List`1 settings,
> >     Component relatedComponent, String filename, String variantName,
> >     StructureGroup sg, Boolean isArray)    at
> >     Sdl.Web.Tridion.Common.TemplateBase.PublishJsonData(Dictionary`2
> >     settings, Component relatedComponent, String variantName,
> >     StructureGroup sg, Boolean isArray)    at
> >     Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.PublishConfiguration.Transform(Engine
> >     engine, Package package)    at
> >     Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.AssemblyMediator.Transform(Engine
> >     engine, Template template, Package package)    at
> >     Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.RunTemplate(Engine
> >     engine, Package package, String templateUri, String className)    at
> >     Tridion.Templating.CSharpTemplate.CSharpSourceTemplate.Transform(Engine
> >     __engine, Package __package)    at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.Transform(Engine
> >     engine, Template template, Package package)    at
> >     Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template
> >     template, Package package)    at
> >     Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package
> >     package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
> >     at
> >     Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine
> >     engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package)    at
> >     Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template
> >     template, Package package)    at
> >     Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package
> >     package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
> >     at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformPackage(Template
> >     template, Package package)    at
> >     Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformItem(Template
> >     template, IdentifiableObject itemToRender)    at
> >     Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.TemplatingRenderer.Render(ResolvedItem
> >     resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget
> >     target, RenderedItem renderedItem, RenderContext renderContext)    at
> >     Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderEngine.Render(ResolvedItem
> >     resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget
> >     target, RenderContext context)    at
> >     Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderEngine.Render(IdentifiableObject
> >     item, Template template, PublishInstruction instruction,
> >     PublicationTarget target, RenderContext context)    at
> >     Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderEngine.Render(IdentifiableObject
> >     item, Template template, PublishInstruction instruction,
> >     PublicationTarget target)    at
> >     Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.RenderItem(TcmUri
> >     itemId, IdentifiableObjectData itemDeltaData, TcmUri templateId,
> >     TemplateData templateDeltaData, PublishInstructionData
> >     publishInstruction, String publicationTargetId)    at
> >     Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.RenderItem(String
> >     itemId, String templateId, PublishInstructionData publishInstruction,
> >     String publicationTargetId)    at SyncInvokeRenderItem(Object ,
> >     Object[] , Object[] )    at
> >     System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
> >     instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    at
> >     Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceInvoker.Invoke(Object
> >     instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    at
> >     System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
> >     rpc)    at
> >     System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
> >     rpc)    at
> >     System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
> >     rpc)    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
> >     isOperationContextSet)

We Imported DXA Blueprint in our existing Blueprint.
Any help in finding the root cause. Thanks

Comment: Is this an OOTB DXA BluePrint? Did you import into an existing BluePrint? Did you create your own Module?

Comment: We are using the DXA blueprint only, but we have customize few default Tbbs. Actually everything was working fine, and we were able to publish the Publish Settings Page too. But today only we are getting issue.

Comment: When we are previewing the Core component with the CT Publish Settings, it throwing this error **(80040356) Invalid parameter: variantId (schemasform%20core.schemas).**

Comment: Which DXA version?

Comment: DXA version 1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception occurs in the DXA PublishConfiguration TTB. That TBB creates (JSON) binaries with information about the Schemas for each Module. These binaries are named `<modulename>.schemas.json` and also have that name (excl. file extension) as variant ID.

The exception occurs because `schemasform%20core.schemas` is not considered a valid variant ID. Apparently, you have a Module called `schemasform%20core`, which is a rather unusual name (looks like the Core Module which has been renamed).

These Module names are obtained from the Module Configuration Components (from the `name` field).

Comment: checked the Core component which is using Module Configuration Schema, there Module Name (name) value is **Core**. I think its correct only.

Comment: In DXA 1.2, the Module name was obtained from the Module's Folder Name. Or actually, the Folder's WebDAV URL, which is probably the reason for the %20: the Folder could be called `Schemasform Core`.

Comment: Thank you Rick, for this clear information. We had one more folder inside Module folder other then Core folder. We deleted that second folder from there and it started publishing. :)